# How do I add the theme javascript files with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I did a lot of research on Webpack but I couldn't solve my problem.
I bought a theme: DatavizUI Template.
I can add this theme to the application I created with rails 6 using "sprockets". But I want to add this with webpack. The javascript files of the theme do not work when I add via Webpack.

```
ruby -v : 2.6.5p114
rails -v : 6.0.2.2
```

Javascript console errors:

## 1:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined
at formpickers.js:1
at Object. (formpickers.js:13)
at Object../app/javascript/packs/formpickers.js (formpickers.js:90)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19)
at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:26)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19)
at bootstrap:83
at bootstrap:83

## 2:

template.js:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: PerfectScrollbar is not defined
at applyStyles (template.js:63)
at HTMLDocument. (template.js:57)
at mightThrow (deferred.js:97)
at process (deferred.js:139)

Comment: what is th issue ??

Comment: The problem is that the theme doesn't work when I introduce javascript files with webpack.

Comment: very broad term, if you can paste error u get.. it will be easy for other to help

Comment: seems like its calling variables or elements which have not been defined before... so maybe its your `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in application.html.erb? Is it located at the bottom of the body?